# Cannot access functions inside Javascript function wrapper?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

All,

My code was failing JSLint for the "use strict" issue.
As suggested here : [Disable "use the function form of use strict" but keep the "Missing 'use strict' statement" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953654/disable-use-the-function-form-of-use-strict-but-keep-the-missing-use-strict)

If you wrap all the functions in the javascript file with another function wrapper, it will solve this issue.

However now after doing this all my functions are undefined when I call them from the page?

```
(function () {
"use strict";

/**
 * Update the page with a message informing the user
 * an email has been sent to their email address
 * @param details user details (email address)
 */
function shareEmailSent(details) {

    // unhide confirmation message
    $('strong#emailAddress').text(details.email);
    $('#confirmationMessage').removeClass('hide');
}

/**
 * Handle error
 */
function showError() {
    return false;
}

/**
 * Makes a POST request to send the current user
 * an email containing their unqiue share url
 * @param emailList
 */
function sendEmail(emailList) {
    var data = {};
    data.formToken = $('#formToken').val();
    data.emails = emailList;
    $.mooAjax({
        url: "/ajax/share/refer_a_friend_email.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        error: showError,
        success: function (response) {
            shareEmailSent(response);
        }
    });
}
}());
```

e.g.

> shareEmailSent is not defined

How can I fix this but also pass the JSLint issue as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches you can take. In descending order of niceness:

1. Don't call the functions from outside. Bind all your event handlers using JavaScript (e.g. with `addEventListener`)
2. Use [the revealing module pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647258/how-to-use-revealing-module-pattern-in-javascript)
3. Explicitly make functions globals (e.g. with `window.someFunction = someFunction`).

Obviously, since `sendEmail` calls the other functions itself, it is probably the only one that would need to be exposed if you used the second or third approach.

Comment: Thanks, for the help. I went with option 3. 
However now it breaks my functions validation for some reason, any idea why assigning a function to a global variable would affect the logic?

Comment: It shouldn't do, and I've no idea what you mean by "breaks my functions validation".